# How to close dropdown menu using own useOnOutsideClick hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I faced a problem with my mobile drowdown menu. I'd like to close dropdown by clicking outside (somewhere, let's say on titels above) of my button and dropdown items.

This is my
[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-borg-09qyh?file=/src/App.js).

Menu

```
const Menu = () => {
  const [isMobileNavOpen, setMobileNavState] = useState(false);

  const mobileNavRef = useRef();

  useOnOutsideClick(mobileNavRef, () => {
    if (isMobileNavOpen) setMobileNavState(false);
  });

  const toggleMobileNav = () => {
    setMobileNavState(!isMobileNavOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="dropdown" ref={mobileNavRef}>
        <button
          className="dropdown-btn"
          onClick={toggleMobileNav}
          type="button"
        >
          DROPDOWN BUTTON
        </button>
        {isMobileNavOpen && (
          <div
            className="dropdown-menu"
            onClick={() => setMobileNavState(false)}
          >
            <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Item1
            </a>
            <a className="dropdown-item" href="#">
              Item2
            </a>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

my hook useOnClickOutside

```
export const useOnOutsideClick = (ref, callback) => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (ref.current && ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      callback();
      console.log("click");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  });
};
```

Please about any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flip the contains logic of your `useOutsideClick` hook. You want to check of the click event originated from ***not*** within the target element the ref is attached to.

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
  if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target)) {
    callback();
    console.log("click");
  }
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-close-dropdown-menu-using-own-useonoutsideclick-hook]

Entire hook

```
export const useOnOutsideClick = (ref, callback) => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (!ref.current?.contains(e.target)) {
      callback();
      console.log("click");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    };
  });
};
```